# How to hide all plugins installed in a WP site?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want to hide all the plugins installed in my site. How I can achieve this. I tried with the following but it does not seem to work.

```
function hide_plugins($plugins)
{   
    if ( ! function_exists( 'get_plugins' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';
}
   $plugins = get_plugins();
   foreach($plugins as $plugin){
        if (in_array($plugin, array_keys($plugins))) {
            unset($plugins[$plugin]);
        }
   }
    return $plugins;
}

add_filter('all_plugins', 'hide_plugins');
```

Source : http://www.wpstuffs.com/hide-installed-plugins-from-dashboard-users-can-not-deactivate-the-plugin/

Comment: Can you clarify as to what you mean by hide? Hide from where? Uninstall or? You can always disable them.

Comment: Sorry for being vague. hide from the plugins page plugins.php

Comment: Hide them, but let them still be active? Hide them from certain users? I mean, if you hide them from all, how will you update them, or add and remove them? I'd use css for this. Add inline style and just hide them using `display:none`.

Comment: Yeah, hiding can be done using CSS but still it will show the count in the plugins list. I want them delisted even though they will rename functional. Source http://www.wpstuffs.com/hide-installed-plugins-from-dashboard-users-can-not-deactivate-the-plugin/

Comment: Try this: `add_filter('all_plugins', '__return_empty_array');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need anything fancy.

```
add_filter('all_plugins', '__return_empty_array');
```

That does the trick for me.

Comment: Man!! You saved my day. Sometimes we go after complex things when easier options are available. I did not think of this earlier at all. Many Thanks for this. :)